# SharePoint List Drop Down only to display choices not already in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, choice-field, powerapps-forms

My SharePoint list is connected to Power Apps . I am trying to create a way to check out equipment by SN.

I have placed the SNs in a Choices Column and put the SNs. This has allowed the user to see available phones by SN. As a selection is made I want to filter it out of the choices available so it cannot be selected by the user.

I have tried using:

```
if(LookUp(Choices('list name'.column name'), 'listname.columnName = DataCardVale.Selected, Notify("change",Notification.warning),
```

I am sorry I forgot what else I had, but it didnt work anyway.

Is this even possible or should I be looking at this a different way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is SN works in your forms and I assume you are trying to filter a Choice column in you powerapps form. I guess it may be better for you to use the `in` operator to filter the choice column as it is a bit different.

Reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-filter-choices-on-Combobox/td-p/101436

And it is a issue which relates to Power Apps more. I would suggest you to post your question with more details and list/form setup in the Power Apps forum. The experts there will be happy to help: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/bd-p/PowerAppsForum1